# whole PC stops responding after starting Texture painting

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I tried to make an island and wanted to make a mask for the landscape so that I can separate sand from grass but right after clicking with brush PC just stops responding and I can't do anything except minimizing blender and try moving mouse 1/2 frames per second and I can't close blender also so only way to close blender is to force restart PC.

My PC isn't the strongest Ryzen5 2600, GTX1070 and 16gb DDR4. but it handled even more larger scenes. the scene I have issues with has 100k faces 30 of are from the model I paint on the model is 60x60m wide and about 20m hight  the texture resolution is 4k no alpha no 32bit, just black.

Except this normally I could paint over a 8K textures with more then 10 million faces in a single scene with some noticeable slowdowns but still make able.

[image]

Comment: ("Ryzen5 2600" <cries maniacally in Phenom II X6>) Have you tried to use a different HDRi or disabling it?

Comment: HDRI was added after i gave up on texture paintinng the surface to preview the water look

Comment: What size of brush are you using in relation to the object texture, or better worded, how far out are you zoomed away and trying to paint on the texture? If the brush is large area compared to the texture, then your computer is being told to affect a lot of texture space at once. Have you tried to paint the same way in Solid View with flat display?

Comment: i found out the problem the UV map was like 20x bigger then the texture now i can paint in texture paint and image paint without problems. thanks